# Div onClick With JSON Call Doesn't Work

Tags: php, jquery, json, html, alert

I have a search function that calls a php file onkeyup. Now in JQuery i have a onClick function that when you click a div from that same JSON call it alerts something, maybe it will be easier to understand from my code below:

```
<?php
$Connect = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "Data");
$Val = $_POST['Val'];

if($Val)
{
    $Search = 'SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ';
    $Term = explode(" ", $Val);

    foreach($Term as $Key)
    {
        $I = 0;
        $I++;
        if($I == 1)
        {
            $Search .= 'Username LIKE "'.$Key.'%" LIMIT 0, 10 ';
        }
        else
        {
            $Search .= 'OR Username LIKE "'.$Key.'%" LIMIT 0, 10 ';
        }
    }

    if($Result = $Connect->query($Search))
    {
        while($Row = $Result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $User = $Row['Username'];

            $USearch['S'][] = '<div class="Result"><label class="TText" style="cursor:pointer;">' . $User . '</label></div>';
        }
    }
}
echo json_encode($USearch);
?>
```

Now, as you can see, once the user types into a box a div shows up showing all LIKE records of Users, once the div is clicked on nothing happens.

```
$('.Result').click(function()
{
    alert('Hi');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the ajax call return a state of success you can use for example the jquery bind method. (see here for more info http://api.jquery.com/bind/ )

```
 function myAjaxFunct(val){

   $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: myPhpFile.php,
        datatype: "jsonp",
        data: {val: val},
        success: function (result) {

            $("#jsonResultDisplay").text(result);

            $('.Result').bind('click', function() {
               alert('hi');
            }); 
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are dynamically creating element that is why it doesn't work.

Use `on()`method.

Check an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/pZQ8T/